# Receiving complaints for SES transactional emails - are TiS notifications generated by filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We're doing everything we can think of to limit the number of complaints we receive and will immediately remove anyone who marks us as junk that does not need to receive our emails. However, the last handful of complaints we've received have come from transactional emails of people who are receiving our company's services and NEED to receive everything we send transactionally as a critical part of our service. (e.g. We are booking their travel on their behalf and we need to send them verification emails to confirm their booking details.)

We're assuming that most of these complaints are somehow either false positives or are being done on accident. One customer confirmed that they did not click the junk mail button but it ended up in their junk folder and they moved it to their inbox. Some questions:

- Can a TiS complaint be triggered by any means other than the user manually marking an email as junk in their email client? (Can automatic spam filters trigger this complaint? AWS documentation specifies only clicking the junk button.)
- Besides contacting each individual personally, what would you suggest we do? Our complaint rate is continuing to rise even though we are taking action on every one.